# Cannot download RDP file

Tags: google-compute-engine

[I am trying to download RDP file, but as shown in the picture, SSH is the only option available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDEXQ.png)

Comment: Is that a Linux virtual machine?

Comment: If you can use SSH to connect, you should be able to connect via `scp` or `sftp` as well

Answer (score 1):

When you use a VM instance on Compute Engine by default the SSH button appears when the VM instance are running a Linux OS.

RDP protocol is only for Windows Server Instances, are you sure you VM was deployed with a Windows Public Image?

Here you can find information about how to connect using a graphical RDP client on Windows Instances.[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_gui)

Also, as an alternative, you can use an interactive serial console, or the Windows Special Administrative Console (SAC), which is often used for advanced troubleshooting on Windows instances.[2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_cli)

I recommend you take a look to this Quickstart guide, here explains how to create a Windows virtual machine instance in Compute Engine using the Google Cloud Platform Console.[3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows)

In some situations, you might not be able to connect to your Google Compute Engine Windows instance via RDP. This problem can be due to any number of network or configuration error.
This link describes a number of tips and approaches to troubleshoot and resolve common RDP issues.[4](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp)

I hope you find this information useful.
See you!

Links:

[1. Connect using a graphical RDP client](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_gui)

[2. Connect to a Windows instance using the command line](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#windows_cli)

[3. Quickstart Using a Windows VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows)

[4. Troubleshooting RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp)